# How to fit all available height inside element

Tags: html, css

Here's an [example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/haGWe/3/).
Excerpt of code:

```
<table style="height:100%">
    <tr height="20"><td></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>This gray cell fits all available height of table</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20"><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

There is a table with three rows. Row in the middle fits all available height of table.
I took this solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118566/fit-td-height-to-page).

Problem is that impossible to make overflow-y for middle cell. It seems that the middle cell has a min-height property equals height of it's content.
So does it possible to turn on scrolling (overflow-y:auto) somehow and if it doesn't how to implement this layout in divs?

UPD. Thanks. Seems like this is working example: http://jsfiddle.net/haGWe/6/
But it's still interesting how to implement this with divs.

Comment: UPD2. And here it is in divs [http://jsfiddle.net/6Q7L7/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/6Q7L7/1/) .

Comment: Np :) Please contribute by marking a solution that worked for you as "Accepted Answer", Thx and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/haGWe/5/) it is.

Basically, add a div inside your td element, add a fixed height (I chose `20px`) and `overflow: auto`.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the contents of middle row in a `div` and apply the css to the `div`.

```
<div class="widget">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr class="widget-header">
        <td>20 px above</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="widget-content">
        <td><div id="myDiv">This gray cell fits all available height of table. What happens when more text is added to this? Woot, scrolls bars.</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="widget-footer">
        <td>20 px below</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

.widget{
    position:absolute;
    min-width:200px;
    width:200px;
    outline:1px solid gray;
    right:50%;
    top:20px;
}
.widget > table{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.widget-header{
    height:20px;
}
.widget-content{
    vertical-align:top;
    background:gray;
}
.widget-footer{
    height:20px;
}
#myDiv
{
    height:40px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2YvG6/

Comment: Oh, you beat me to answer :-)